# Jetpack compose write and read local file?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create and write to a local internal file. I've tried the methods [on this page](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-access-files), but nothing seems to be valid when I implement them as described.

```kotlin
Button(
  modifier = Modifier
    .padding(20.dp,10.dp,20.dp,10.dp),
  shape = RoundedCornerShape(100.dp),
  onClick = {

  val file = getFilesDir() //shows as unresolved reference
  val file = File(context.filesDir, someFileName) // unresolved reference to context als

 }
)
```

I have a compose button that onClick should encode an object to a string I then need to create a file if it has not been created or add to the Json string array

Comment: Please, provide your code implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is calling with context. This can be done using

`LocalContext.current`

Using `val context = LocalContext.current` I was able to use the methods described in documentation without problem